# Why order topology is defined with open intervals, not closed ones?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) *order topology* is defined by the subbase consisting of $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$.

Why is not it defined by intervals $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ instead? Is this Wikipedia definition (with open intervals) accepted by all or absolute most of mathematicians?

Consider an one-point ordered set (call this point $0$). With the Wikipedia definition we have an empty subbase. Isn't it better to have the subbase consisting of the set $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you define the intervals $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ to be open, then you just get the discrete topology.  Indeed, for any $a$ in your set, $\{a\}=[a,\infty)\cap(-\infty,a]$ would be open.  On the other hand, defining it with open intervals gives the standard topology in the case of $\mathbb{R}$, which is pretty strong evidence that this definition is useful at least in some contexts.

There is nothing wrong with having an empty subbase.  When generating a topology from a subbase, you can take finite intersections of your subbase sets.  This includes the intersection of *no* subbase sets (the intersection of all the elements of the empty subset of the subbase), which gives you the entire space.

Comment: Oh sorry, really stupid question by me